# Correctly infer dynamic subclasses in a superclass

Tags: typescript

Let's say we have a simple inheritance case:

```
class Animal {
  // Return a shallow copy with all prototype functions
  getClone(): Animal {
    return Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)), this);
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  woof() { console.log('Woof'); }
}
```

So at the first glance this code works fine. But, when I try to use `getClone()` from a Dog instance:

```
const dog = new Dog();
// Invalid since the superclass Animal doesn't contain the function woof()
dog.getClone().woof();
```

Of course, I can always fix this error by overriding getClone() in an object-oriented way:

```
class Dog extends Animal {
  woof() { console.log('Woof'); }
  getClone(): Dog {
    return super.getClone();
  }
}
```

But let's say the project scales up and I need to create 100 animal classes. Would it be such a hassle to write an override function in every class? Also, if I need to add a function to the base Animal class, would I need to overload it in every subclass?

So, I've sort of come up with a temporary solution: use generics.

```
class Animal<T> {
  getClone(): T {
    return Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)), this);
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal<Dog> {
  woof() { console.log('Woof'); }
}
```

Well this code works quite fine without a TSLint or compilation error. However, is it really safe if we add the generic to the superclass immediately after the class is created?

It also has an expected flaw. Assuming we have a function called `changeNameThenGet(name: string)`. If the name is not provided or somehow invalid, it will return itself:

```
class Animal<T> {
  name = 'Some Animal';
  getClone(): T {
    return Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)), this);
  }
  changeNameThenGet(name: string): T {
    if (!name) {
      // Typescript error. 'this' is an instance of Animal, not T
      return this;
    }
    const newAnimal = this.getClone();
    newAnimal.name = name;
    return newAnimal;
  }
}
```

It seems that Typescript does not recognize that T is a subclass of Animal, and I'm trying to find a way to properly make it work. Note that `class Animal<T extends Animal<any>>` doesn't work as well. There's a way around this as I could just say `return this as any`, but at the end of the day it's just a workaround.

So what do you guys think is the right approach for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic approach is usually used since there is no way in most languages to tell a method in the base class it returns whatever the current type is. Fortunately Typescript is not most languages. Typescript allows the usage of `this` as a type in non-static methods, and is exactly what you need:

```
class Animal {
    // Return a shallow copy with all prototype functions
    getClone(): this {
        return Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)), this);
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    woof() { console.log('Woof'); }
}

new Dog().getClone().woof();
```

This is the [Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3694) that introduces the feature.